# how to use add_step from recipes package in r

Tags: r, r-recipes

I want to build a function that adds steps to a recipe, but I can't figure out how to use `add_step`. It doesn't help that there are no examples in the documentation.

This is what I've tried:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(recipes))

rec1 <- recipe(data = mtcars, mpg ~ disp + hp)
rec1
#> Data Recipe
#> 
#> Inputs:
#> 
#>       role #variables
#>    outcome          1
#>  predictor          2

rec2 <- add_step(rec = rec1, step_mutate(hp = 1))
#> Error in add_step(recipe, step_mutate_new(terms = terms, trained = trained, : argument "recipe" is missing, with no default
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for `step_mutate` does the work of calling `add_step` for you. So you are basically doing it twice. It should look more like

```
rec2 <- rec1 %>% step_mutate(hp = 1)
```

Comment: So `add_step` is only useful for creating custom steps? The goal is to be able to add a series of new steps in sequence to the end of a recipe where the new steps are passed as arguments to a function. I'm guessing I need to use some quosure magic.

Comment: Yes. If you're going to create a custom step you could use it but even then to be like the other functions, a user might not call it directly. You would use it inside your own custom step to add itself to the recipe.